# scss files are compiled and merged into a single css file

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I have following directory structure

```
sass
    modules
        _header.scss
        _footer.scss
    styles.scss
css
    styles.css
```

Whereas my styles.scss file has following code

```
@import "modules/header";
@import "modules/footer";
```

Now when I execute `compass compile` command, all of my styles in header and footer and merged into styles.css. What I want is that all scss files should compile separately and should be imported in styles.css file. **How can I achieve this?**

Comment: I am following that link but it still compiles only styles.scss file to styles.css file. It is ignoring the rest of scss files.

Comment: The real question is:  why would you want to do this???  http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/

Answer (score 2):

.sass/.scss files that start with an underscore don't get compiled unless they're imported; if you want those to compile separately, rename them to "header.scss" and "footer.scss".